# Jasmine: Trying to test an AngularJS factory function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am totally new to testing in AngularJS. I have setup karma, and am now attempting to test a certain function in a factory I have written.

Here is a snippet of my factory:

```
app.factory('helpersFactory', ['constants', function (constants) {
    return {

        someFunction: function() {
        },

        is24x24Icon: function (iconNum) {
            return ((iconNum >= 10090 && iconNum <= 10125) ;
        }
    };

 }]);
```

I then have this test:

```
describe('Factory: helpersFactory', function () {

    beforeEach(module('ppMobi'));

    var fct;
    beforeEach(inject(function ($factory) {
        fct = $factory('helpersFactory');
    }));

    it('should detect iconNum 10090 is a 24 x 24 icon', function () {

        var iconNum = 10090;
        var is24x24Icon = fct.is24x24Icon(iconNum);
        expect(is24x24Icon).toBeTruthy();

    });
});
```

I get an error from Karma telling me it cannot read 'is24x24icon' of undefined. Therefore I can only assume my factory has not been created properly during the test. I do have a dependency on constants in the factory used by other functions. This is just an angular.constant() I have setup on my main application module.

I have found some other posts, but am unsure how to proceed, do I need to inject my constants dependency into my test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of new myself but I think you need to use the underscore name underscore trick to inject your factory:

```
var fct;
beforeEach(inject(function (_helpersFactory_) {
    fct = _helpersFactory_;
}));
```

This blog uses mocha but I found it useful and the Karma stuff should be the same:  https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/testing-angular-with-karma

And yes you will need to inject the constants as well (the link shows how) but your posted code does not seem to use constants so you won't need it for this particular test.